# Unenforced Unique vs enforced Unique in memsql

Tags: singlestore

I find this abit confusing. Iam using memsql column store. I try to understand if there is a way to enforce duplications on specific key (e.g eventId). I found some doc regarding Unenforced Unique but I didnt really understand its intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of unenforced unique keys is as a hint:

> An unenforced unique constraint is informational: the query planner may use the unenforced unique constraint as a hint to choose better query plans.

from https://docs.memsql.com/v6.8/concepts/unenforced-unique-constraints/.

Unfortunately MemSQL does not support (enforced) unique constraints on columnstore tables.

Comment: thanks for that. any ideas how to enforce this? any other suggestions ?

Comment: The main way to do it is to enforce it as part of the load process, which requires some application logic. E.g. before and after inserting a record check if a duplicate exists. Or to process a batch of data to insert, you can insert it into a staging rowstore table, join with the columnstore table to find duplicates, and then insert the deduplicated values into the columnstore table.

Comment: Also support for unique constraints (enforced) on columnstore tables is on the roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

MemSQL now supports unique constraint with version 7+ but can be applied to only single column:

https://docs.memsql.com/v7.1/guides/use-memsql/physical-schema-design/creating-a-columnstore-table/creating-a-columnstore-table/

Your columnstore table definition can contain metadata-only unenforced unique keys, **single-column hash keys (which may be UNIQUE)**, and a FULLTEXT key. You cannot define more than one unique key.

one hack to **enable UNIQUE constraint on multi columns is to use a computed column consisting of multiple columns appended and then apply UNIQUE on it** which will indirectly enforce uniqueness on multiple columns.

example:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED,
    year int UNSIGNED,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    body TEXT,
    SHARD KEY(title),
    KEY (id) USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE,
    KEY (id) USING HASH,     
    UNIQUE KEY (title) USING HASH,
    KEY (year) USING HASH);
```